# Can you prioritize events in libuv?

Tags: libuv

Let's say I have 2 sockets I am watching for events and I really want socket 1 to be preferred (event at the cost of starving socket 2). How would I do that with libuv ?

As an example when working with libevent one can use :

`int event_priority_set(struct event *event, int priority);`

> When multiple events of multiple priorities become active, the
>   low-priority events are not run. Instead, Libevent runs the high
>   priority events, then checks for events again. Only when no
>   high-priority events are active are the low-priority events run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that in libuv.  In libuv there is no abstraction for an event (so no `struct event` or some equivalent stuff), all i/o callbacks are dispatched as they happen.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to stick with libevent I guess :)